# libxml2 error when building build_native.sh on cocos2d-x

Tags: libxml2, cocos2d-x

I am creating a hybrid iOS/android game using cocos2d-x as the game engine. in the iOS side the project doesn't have any problem loading the libxml2 library. but when i build the build_native.sh in the android side, the script return an error like this

```
error: libxml2/libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
```

I already tried to modify the android.mk file but it nothing good happened.
how should i link the libxml2 library in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct folder is

```
libxml2/include/libxml/tree.h
```

Check the Original files in the

```
cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/modules.
```

the version I am using is 0.12.0

Comment: ah found it.. but how to include it to the project?
and which is the correct #include way? #include <libxml2> or #include "libxml2" ?

Comment: if you just want to use that file, you can include the whole path, which is cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/moduleslibxml2/include/libxml/tree.h .